# HTML table columns change width when inline block elements are added to table spanning column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table that displays data from a number of different products. Each row of product data is followed by a table spanning row that shows more details about the product. In my table I allow the user to show or hide these details as they wish. The problem I have is that when this data is shown the column widths resize even though the details row spans the whole table. I have narrowed the problem down to `inline-block` elements that are present in the details row. When these elements wrap, the column widths for some reason get affected.

In the picture below you can see the effect taken from this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6qanb8dk/. The widths of the columns all change slightly due to the wrapping `inline-block` elements in the details part of the second table, which is otherwise identical to the first table. Here the effect is not huge but in my actual application the table moves around enough to be annoying to the user. I would like to know why this is happening and how it can be prevented.

[image: changing-column-widths]

Comment: Interesting. I believe that two calculations happen in a row: first the "natural" widths of the tables is calculated (which would make the first table narrower than the second one) and then the first one gets recalculated to add some space to each column, because it needs to be 100% wide. This apparently result in different widths per column. I can't think of a solution though.

Comment: for me , if i resize the fiddle untill the last world what? wraps to next line, this the first th that wraps on 2 lines . nothing strange since there is not enough width  to keep every th words on a single line ... on both tables .  it might have to do with the font my browser uses and the white-space in between the divs

Comment: @G-Cyr tns not about the layout of the bottom row, but about the width of the columns above, in the OP's screenshot, you can see by the word wrap that the second column is slightly narrower in the second one.

Comment: Right, I see, so the natural width of the table is set by the width where all the `inline-block` elements are distributed without wrapping. And then the recalculation step starts from a different starting point. Maybe I'll have to use some sort of fixed layout for the details items instead.

Comment: It would be nice if there was some way to tell the sizing algorithm to ignore a particular cell in the calculation.

Comment: @jdnz If you do `table-layout:fixed`, the columns will be as wide as the width of the cells in the first row. This would work perfectly well in the example code, where the contents in the th's are the widest.

Comment: I thought this should work, but when I tried adding `table-layout: fixed` to the `table` css style in the example fiddle I still see the columns changing at different points when I resize the window. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?